# Is it possible to UI automate testing involving Two-factor Authentication for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, automated-testing

I have an iOS app that uses 2FA for certain account related features. I'd like to create some UI automation tests for those features, but they require receiving either SMS messages or email. On a simulator, there is no such way to access SMS. I think it might be possible to access the email instead, but that would involve opening up Mobile Safari and logging into an email account- do iOS automation frameworks even support that level of granularity for accessing UIWebViews?.

Is it even possible to have automated tests for 2FA? One presumes that if there's a way to access the test account's SMS or email accounts- so on a device, not in the simulator- it might be feasible.

Comment: Although this is testing 2FA, this is more of a QA question than an InfoSec question.

Comment: I would recommend updating the original question with this one.  Much more likely to get an actual answer.